# Anchor tag with mailto and javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Below is my piece of code, I am trying to invoke a javascript function and mailto when user clicks a anchor-link, my javascript function is throwing errors, if I remove mailto it works fine. Please advise if I am missing anything here.

```
    <a rel="nofollow" onclick="javascript:confirm('2R','ADDRESS');return true;" href="mailto:housing@test.edu?
subject=Incorrect Residential Address">housing@test.edu (Click Here)</a>
```

here is my confirm function which has ajax call

```
    function confirm(addcode,type){

     $.ajax({
            url: 'https://mysite.url/confirm',
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'POST',
            cache : false,
             beforeSend: function setHeader(xhr){
                 console.log(addcode + '<--->'+type+'<--->'+term);
                $("#main-content").mask("Please wait...");
            },
            data: {
                'addCode': addcode,
                'type': type,
                'termCode' : term
            },
            success: function(data){
                notify("Confirmed");
                $("#main-content").unmask(); 
            },
            error: function(xhr, testStatus, error) {
                $("#main-content").unmask(); 
                notify("Unable to Confirm");

                console.log(error);
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(testStatus);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: What error? Can you share it

Comment: Seems to work -> http://jsfiddle.net/S5jHS/

Comment: sure, you need to tell us the error and show us the javascript code

Comment: If it's the function that's throwing the error then we need to see that.

Comment: the confirm function is defined by me in java-script and it has a ajax call,

Comment: Any idea or need more details?

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet:
I think it isn't a real 'error', more that the code doesn't work as he expects it to.

- you want a confirm box before you activate 'mailto:'.
- if user presses yes, then it will activate it.
- if the user presses no, you want it to do nothing.

Here a crossbrowser solution:
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kychan/9KuLM/

```
function mConfirm(e, a)
{
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to send it to: ' + a + '?'))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        e.preventDefault();
}
```

### edit:

btw. you can't change the title of a confirm box. The 'confirm()' function only works with 1 argument. If you insist on making a confirm box with a title you should use a third-party script or your own function.